# Racing condition in locked async methods

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, .net-5

I'm creating a Blazor Server App that does some `async` DB access when loading controls.

I've created a DB locker class to make sure I'm not opening two transactions simultaneously when using Sqlite for example. The goal is to control the number of parallel transactions - here, I restrict it to 1.

I am facing a racing condition bug here, but I can't spot what actually happens and why I actually get `threadSyncCount > 1`.

My DB locker class looks like this:

```
public static class DBLocker {
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static object _lockObject = new object();
    static int threadSyncCount = 0;

    public static bool WaitForDBAccess(bool forceWait = false) {
        bool lockWasTaken = false;
        TimeSpan tSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 500);
        int delayCount = 0;
        // --- make sure we get the lock
        while (!lockWasTaken) {
            if (threadSyncCount == 0) {
                Monitor.TryEnter(_lockObject, tSpan, ref lockWasTaken);
            }
            else {
                await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(50, 150));
            }
            ++delayCount;
            // --- sometimes it's just OK to leave without getting the lock => just skip waiting,
            //     the caller method will just return without any DB access in this case!
            if (!forceWait && delayCount > 5) {
                // --- NB: this actually never happens!
                if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
                return false;
            }
       }
       // -- so we got the lock - we "should" be certain threadSyncCount == 0
       // --- but well, it is NOT the case, following DOES occur!!!!
       if (threadSyncCount != 0) {
           throw new Exception("DB lock error: freed acces more than it was locked - Lock counter is " + threadSyncCount);
       }
       Interlocked.Increment(ref threadSyncCount);
       if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
       return true;
    }


    // --- Method to release the DB locks!
    public static void FreeDBAccess() {
        // local starts here => locks the DB access (prevents multiple concurrent DB access)!!
        if (threadSyncCount != 1) {
            // --- this actually happens => sometimes threadSyncCount == 2 here!!!
            throw new Exception("DB lock error: freed acces more than it was locked - Lock counter is " + threadSyncCount);
        }
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadSyncCount);
    }
}
```

Lock method is called from DB access methods, prior to opening a transaction to the DB.

Method calls would be someting like this:

```
public async Task DBSync() {
    // ---- wait for the lock
    if (!await DBLocker.WaitForDBAccess(false)) {
        return;
    }
    // ---- 
    await doSomeDBLoading();
    // ---
    DBLocker.FreeDBAccess();
}
```

Why is the above code subject to race-condition bugs? Any suggestion as per how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `WaitForDBAccess` method takes and then releases the mutex, and `FreeDBAccess` does not release the mutex, so the mutex is not held during the time the DB access is performed.

Even after fixing this, there's another problem: mutexes are "recursive".

Mutexes are a pre-`async` kind of synchronization primitive that only cares about mutual exclusion of *threads*. So, if a Mutex is entered and the *current thread* already owns it, then the lock is granted. This [does not play well with asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html), where "the same thread" no longer means "recursive".

The proper way to handle this is to use a synchronization primitive that is `async`-aware (or at least one that doesn't support "recursive" locks). There is one built-in: `SemaphoreSlim`. E.g.:

```
public static class DBLocker
{
  static SemaphoreSlim _lockObject = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
  static int threadSyncCount = 0;

  public static async Task<bool> WaitForDBAccessAsync(bool forceWait = false)
  {
    TimeSpan tSpan = forceWait ? Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5 * 500 + 0.5);
    bool lockWasTaken = await _lockObject.WaitAsync(tSpan);
    if (!lockWasTaken)
      return false;

    if (threadSyncCount != 0)
      throw new Exception("DB lock error: freed acces more than it was locked - Lock counter is " + threadSyncCount);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref threadSyncCount);
    return true;
  }

  public static void FreeDBAccess()
  {
    if (threadSyncCount != 1)
      throw new Exception("DB lock error: freed acces more than it was locked - Lock counter is " + threadSyncCount);
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadSyncCount);
    _lockObject.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your code is way simpler and clearer - awesome! One thing though - waiting 2500.5s seems a bit strange - guess it should be `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500)?` or so?
Another tought: threads are all started within a few milliseconds - is there a way to "distribute" their execution uniformly in time with the lock above?

Comment: @neggenbe: The `TimeSpan` is using the values from your posted code: 500 seconds retried 5 times with an average of 100ms delay between retries. Use whatever values make sense for your app. I'm not sure what you mean by "distribution"; all threads waiting for the db will just (asynchronously) wait until it's available or the timeout occurs.

Comment: Oh my bad - corrected my code to `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500)` on my side. Now the locking seems perfect. However, for some reason I'm trying to figure out, I get an interlock of 2 threads :
1. thread A takes the DB access and locks it - fine
2. thread A awaits a DB connection to open : `await connection.OpenAsync();`
3. thread B asks for DB access BEFORE A finishes
4. Now both threads are interlocked - A doen't get the connection to open, B also hangs because it's await A to finish.... 
Any idea why this is?

Comment: Ok, in fact I'm executing the async method from a property setter as :
`Task<bool> task = Task.Run<bool>(async () => await _paramsCache.InsertOrUpdate(p));` then retrieving the result : `bool isSaved = task.Result;` - do I have to go down the implementation of both synchronous and async methods to prevent thread locking, or is there a way to call the async method without risking thread locks??

Comment: @neggenbe: Doing sync-over-async (`.Result`) is a separate issue, and an anti-pattern. Usually you can [use something like a "notify task" for a better solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding).

Comment: @neggenbe: In your example, I don't see why A wouldn't get the connection to open. It should open the connection, update the data, and then release the lock.

Comment: well that's the point - I can't figure it out either, but there definitely IS a deadlock... So I'm trying to get rid of the synchronous calls explicitely - which is a bit frustrating, because it basically prevents using property getters/setter to lookup data, we NEED to write explicit async get/set methods... :(